# Flask-Python pick "CHECKBOX" as input database SQLITE3

Tags: python, html

I have the following codes. Once the user fill all textboxes and the checkbox and clicks the submit, each value will be filled in column.
Example: User selected the checkbox with value "HTML", then it will be populate in a column after submit. That way, I would like to know what the checkbox to show on a page. This whole code is working when checkbox is eliminated.

Sqlite3 db model:

```
class students(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('student_id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    city = db.Column(db.String(50))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100))
    language = db.Column(db.String(100))
    addr = db.Column(db.String(200))
    pin = db.Column(db.String(10))
    skills = db.Column(db.String(200))
    def __init__(self, name, city, email, language, addr, pin, skills):
        self.name = name
        self.city = city
        self.email = email
        self.language = language
        self.addr = addr
        self.pin = pin
        self.skills = skills
```

My View decorator is:

```
def addrec():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            name = request.form['name']
            city = request.form['city']
            email = request.form['email']
            language = request.form['language']
            addr = request.form['addr']
            pin = request.form['pin']
            skills = request.form['skills'] 

            with sql.connect("database.db") as con:
                s = request.form.getlist('ch')
                v = ','.join(s)
                cur = con.cursor(v)
                cur.execute('INSERT INTO students (name,city,email,language,addr,pin,skills) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', (name,city,email,language,addr,pin,skills) ) 

            con.commit()
            msg = "success! insert operation"
        except:
            con.rollback()
            msg = "error in insert operation"
        finally:
            return render_template("result.html", msg=msg, name=name, city=city, email=email, language=language, addr=addr, pin=pin, skills=skills)
            con.close()
```

My HTML template is :

```
<html>
<body> 

<form action = "{{ url_for('addrec') }}" method = "POST">
<h3>Employee Information Flask database</h3> 

Name<br>
<input type = "text" name = "name" /></br> 

City<br>
<input type = "text" name = "city" /><br> 

Address<br>
<textarea name = "addr" ></textarea><br> 

Email<br>
<input type = "text" name = "email" /><br> 

Language<br>
<input type = "text" name = "language" /><br> 

PINCODE<br>
<input type = "text" name = "pin" /><br> 

<p>Input your skills defines a skills:</p> 

<input type="checkbox" name="ch" value="HTML"> HTML<br>
  <br><br>
  <input type = "submit" value = "submit" /><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Error.log is:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'msg' referenced before assignment
```

Happens at:

```
File "/home/kamusa/mysite/flask_app.py", line 155, in addrec
return render_template("result.html", msg=msg)
```

I also tried this approach in addrec, but just the same:

```
return render_template("result.html", msg=msg, name=name, city=city, email=email, language=language, addr=addr, pin=pin, skills=skills)
```

I searched and found this thread [How to select multiples checkboxes and insert in MySql with Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53772207/how-to-select-multiples-checkboxes-and-insert-in-mysql-with-flask). And I follow the method but unlucky.
Any help? Thank you

KAmus

Note: a working code is something like this:

```
@app.route('/addrec',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def addrec():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name2 = request.form['name1']
        genre2 = request.form['gen']
        experience2 = request.form['ex']
        education2 = request.form['ed']

        city2 = request.form['city1']
        email2 = request.form['email1']
        language2 = request.form['language1']
        addr2 = request.form['addr1']
        nat2 = request.form['nationality']
        with sql.connect("database.db") as con:
            ch = request.form.getlist('ch')
            skills2 = ', '.join(ch)
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute(
                'INSERT INTO students (name,genre,experience,education,city,email,language,addr,nationality,skills) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
                (name2,genre2,experience2,education2,city2,email2,language2,addr2,nat2,skills2)
            )
        con.commit()
        msg = "success! insert operation"
        con.close()
    return render_template("result.html", msg=msg)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @community, the codes containt error. Thank you

Comment: Which line is "line 155, in addrec"?

Comment: @Xbox One, this line: **return render_template("result.html", msg=msg)**